# How to access span class in codebehind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Is it possible display/hide spans in the codebehind based on their class? 
I've been able to do this with a span's id but not with classes.

markup:

```
<span runat='server' id='myId' class='myClass'>some text</span>
```

codebehind:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    // This works
    myId.Visible = false;

    // This doesn't work
    myClass.Visible = false;
}
```

I get the error "The name myClass does not exist in current context". 
But the codebehind has no trouble with the id.

Comment: Why do you want to access a CLASS??? You will need to use JavaScript if you want to lookup items by class to hide them for example.

Comment: Why not giving us the the background of your problem instead of the solution you are looking for?

Comment: dude 'class' is used for css not for c# code

Comment: Trying to hide or show multiple html elements at once -- I should have specified that. Also curious if it was possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing that exists that lets you refer to something by class; only the ID actually works in the code-behind.  You can find the object by ID, and then check it's class, or you can define a container control around something:

```
<asp:Panel ID="X" runat="server">
.
.
</asp:Panel>
```

And using this, you can loop through the controls in the panel, check the class, and process it, like:

```
foreach (var c in X.Controls)
{
   if (c is WebControl && ((WebControl)c).CssClass == "myClass")
      //Do something
   else if (c is HtmlControl && ((HtmlControl)c).Attributes.ContainsKey("class") && ((HtmlControl)c).Attributes["class"] == "myClass")
      //Do something

}
```

That's possible to do.  You could also do it at the page level, but would have to do it recursively, and it may affect your apps performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<span runat='server' id='myId' class='myClass'>some text</span>
    ...
</span>


myId.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will not. You are using class name as an Id.

You can select the control using Contols Collection on `Page` object.

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
            if (c.CssClass == "myClass")
            {
                c.Visible=false;
            }
    }
```